# plot is not defined ipython?

Tags: python

Using it in ipython

```
def plotcorrected(self, conditions= 'all', strains= 'all'):
    # Plots the corrected fluorescence per cell for all strains in all conditions.
    '''
    S, t= self.d, self.t
    if conditions == 'all':
        cons= S.keys()
    else:
        cons= gu.makelist(conditions)
    for c in cons:
        if strains == 'all':
            strains=  S[c].keys()
        else:
            strains= gu.makelist(strains)
        for s in strains:
            if s != 'null' and s != 'WT':
                plt.figure()
                plt.plot(t, S[c][s]['mg'], '.-')
                plt.plot(t, S[c][s]['mg']+S[c][s]['sg'], 'k:', alpha=0.4)
                plt.plot(t, S[c][s]['mg']-S[c][s]['sg'], 'k:', alpha=0.4)
                plt.xlabel('time (hours)')
                plt.ylabel('corrected fluorescence')
                plt.title('corrected ' + s + ' in ' + c)
                plt.show()
```

But when trying to plot i.e. `plot(t, S['1%gal']['GAL10']['data'][:, 0], '.')` it returns *plot is not defined*

Comment: You should edit your question with code formatting so it's readable.

Comment: You just removed the editing made by a friendly user that made the question much more readable. Pity.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that all your code is commented; what is `plt`?

Answer (score 3):

You [left out](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/pyplot_tutorial.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

from your pasted code.